# MySQL - fetch data where the $var = array?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables like so

`subscribers`

```
id    subscriber     subscribe_to
1       user1          user2
2       user2          user3
3       user1          user2
4       user3          user4
5       user1          user2
6       user1          user7
7       user5          user2
8       user8          user9
9       user1          user10
```

And my other table like so:
`main`

```
id    by_user      post_name
1     user1        somename1
2     user2        somename2
3     user1        somename3
4     user3        somename4
5     user3        somename5
6     user1        somename6
7     user2        somename7
8     user3        somename8
```

I want to use php-mysql to get all the subscriptions of user1 (for example) from table 1. And then pull the common name from table 2 but I am not sure how to fetch the second table

```
$get_subscriptions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `subscriber` = 'user1'");
if(mysql_num_rows($get_subscriptions) == 1){
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_subscriptions);
$subscriptions = $fetch['subscribe_to'];//this will return an array with all the subscribed to users by user1
}
```

Now, I want to fetch the second table and get all the post_name (from $subscriptions). I am not sure how to write the query.

```
$get_posts= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE....");
```

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called a [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Comment: it should be `if(mysql_num_rows($get_subscriptions) >= 1)`

Comment: Is there any relationship between these two tables? And Do you want all posts from main table on the bases of subscriber or subscriber_to or something else?

Comment: yes, when user1 subscribe to user2, I want to start showing the posts of user2 to user1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT post_name FROM main 
WHERE by_user = 'user1' OR by_user IN (SELECT subscribe_to FROM subscribers WHERE subscriber = 'user1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE by_user IN ('" . implode("', '", $subscriptions) . "')");
```